# Zend Apigility REST with Condition

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3, laminas-api-tools

I have a REST API:

```
/api/v1/users
```

Can I get list of only active users (status = 1) without filters?

```
/api/v1/users?filter[0][type]=eq&filter[0][field]=status&filter[0][value]=1
```

And without overloading `fetchAll()`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code (including `fetchAll()`), and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, add an RPC endpoint (with Apigility admin UI, create as a "service", give it a name (e.g. GetActiveUsers) and a route (e.g. /users/active)). That will create `module/users/v1/rpc/whatever` with a Controller and a Factory. Use the Factory to provide the ObjectManager (EntityManager most likely) instance to the Controller. In the Controller get the UserRepository and call the function getActiveUsers in the repo. In that function use the QueryBuilder to get those users. Return result to Controller, return to client.